# Is "tweet" a proper verb now?

Tags: verbs, neologisms, internet, social-media

So I know that in modern English, the word "google" is considered a proper verb now. Can the same be said for the word "tweet" (i.e. to post a 140-char message to Twitter)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Why not?](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tweet)

*Tweet* was already a verb meaning "to chirp", and many people are using the secondary definition of "posting to Twitter". Is there a good reason to not consider it a valid usage considering its adoptance by a great amount of people? English is an evolving language, after all.

Comment: Exactly! If that's what people use, it's a valid word.

Comment: Did you intentionally use the word *adoptance* to make a point?

Comment: Let's say yes and avoid me the embarrassment. @kos

Comment: @waiwai933: Well, I liked it in any case! :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why not. As another example, lots of people have been using the word "text" for years (meaning, of course, "to send a text message.")